# Word vsto Addin not loading in WIndows XP

Tags: visual-studio, ms-word, windows-xp, vsto

I have a small vsto addin for Word that used to work on Word 2010 on Windows XP which was then changed to  work on Word 2010 on windows 7. Now, the client wants that plugin to work again on XP and I can't get it to work. I have started the project from scratch in visual studio 2008 to no avail. The difference between the one for Windows 7 and XP was that Windows 7 used Servicemodel and XP used database calls. I have removed the Servicemodel reference and it still doesn't work. I have enabled Fusion logs and the following is what I got. I have done some research where it said not to put any dependencies for the plugin and to install them manually on every machine that this plugin is to be installed on...however, this doesn't seem like an option in our case, as there are many machines this has to be installed on and the users themselves don't have the admin rights to install programs on their machines. Besides, I didn't have to install anything when it worked. Any inputs?

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

LOG: Start binding of native image eMESAHECOWordAddinXP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
LOG: IL assembly loaded from C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local Settings\Application Data\assembly\dl3\E6C2NQ04.WJ1\GC7HN260.7J2\4c4ce18f\00a69b13_9c16ce01\eMESAHECOWordAddinXP.dll.
WRN: No matching native image found.
LOG: Bind to native image assembly did not succeed. Use IL image.

Comment: check if there is version mismatch of word 32 vs 64 bit, can you share stack trace?

Comment: Thanks for your response but I have resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by setting VSTO_SUPRESSDISPLAYALERTS environment variable to 0. After which Word gave me a popup message stating the issue when it was trying to load the plugin. I installed Office 2007 PIA and everything worked just fine.